# Remove characters from string based on relative position to specific character, in R

Tags: regex, r

How to remove all characters **before** "p", and "p" itself, in all strings of v1 as in data frame below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c("m0p1", "m5p30", "m11p20", "m59p60"))
```

How to remove all characters **after** "p" and "p" itself?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do

```
sub('^[^p]*p', '', df1$v1)
#[1] "1"  "30" "20" "60"
```

Or

```
sub('p.*$', '', df1$v1)
#[1] "m0"  "m5"  "m11" "m59"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gsub`

```
# Remove everything before p
gsub("^.*?p(.*)","\\1",df1$v1,perl=TRUE)
#[1] "1"  "30" "20" "60"

# Remove everything after p
gsub("(.*)?p.*$","\\1",df1$v1,perl=TRUE)
# [1] "m0"  "m5"  "m11" "m59"
```

Answer (score 1):

After p:

```
gsub('.*(?<=p)(\\d+)','\\1',df1$v1,perl=T)
```

Before p:

```
gsub('(.*)(?=p).*','\\1',df1$v1,perl=T)
```